# How do I get Windows Media Player to skip/ignore songs?

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

I have just switched from Itunes to WMP. However, I have several audiobooks and speeches in my library that I do not want to play unless I need to. For example, I don't want an old Tom Clancy novel popping up when I am rocking out. In Itunes, I could just "uncheck" songs to prevent them from playing. How do I accomplish this on Media Player?

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically tag the songs that you want to be excluded from playing, for example by setting their genre to `Speech`. Then create an auto playlist in WMP with a `Genre Is Not Speech` condition, and play that auto playlist instead of using Play all. For more info about auto playlists, see http://thewelltemperedcomputer.com/SW/WMP/Playlist.htm